# Ext.define a view and scope

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.itemsBagPanel', {
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    ...
    validatorFn:function(item,source,target,isSpecial) {
        return false;
    },
    createValidatorFn:function(item,source) {
        return this.validatorFn(item,source,source,false);
    },
    moveValidatorFn: function(item, source, target) {
       return this.validatorFn(item,source,target,true);
    }
```

This is the raw skeleton of my view, and now I need to know how I can access validatorFn from createValidatorFn.
"this" does not work, as it seems.

Comment: How is the createValidatorFn function called? Is there some extra binding happening? ("this" can be "bind" with another context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.itemsBagPanel', {
extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
...
initComponent   : function() {
    itemsBagPanel = this;    //Declaration
    this.items=[{....}];
    this.callParent();
}
validatorFn:function(item,source,target,isSpecial) {
    return false;
},
createValidatorFn:function(item,source) {
    itemsBagPanel.validatorFn(); // You can access other functions
    return this.validatorFn(item,source,source,false);
},
moveValidatorFn: function(item, source, target) {
   return this.validatorFn(item,source,target,true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way would be to use:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.itemsBagPanel', {
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    initComponent   : function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me,{
            createValidatorFn:function(item,source) {
                return me.validatorFn(item,source,source,false);
            },
            moveValidatorFn: function(item, source, target) {
               return me.validatorFn(item,source,target,true);
            }
        });
    },
    validatorFn:function(item,source,target,isSpecial) {
        return false;
    }
```

Note that you have to have the `validatorFn` defined outside `initComponent` (or use two calls to `apply`), because `me.validatorFn` has to be defined before `createValidatorFn` and `moveValidatorFn` can use them.